# Python split key values

Tags: python, json

I have a Json file which I'm parsing data and it's generated output is in output.txt.  At this moment, after the output.txt is generated i'm reading output.txt line by line. Splitting each line and then deleting first two column.

```
("\t".join(line.split()[2:]) + "\n")
```

How can I get the same result from for loop shared below?
Expected output project_name + Files_name.

script.py

```
import json
x = json.load(open('data.json'))
for sub_dict in x['changed']:
    print('project_name', sub_dict['project_name'])

    for entry in sub_dict['added_commits']:
        print (entry['File_Names'])
```

> data.json

```
{
    "changed": [
        {
            "prev_revision": "a09936ea19ddc9f69ed00a7929ea81234af82b95", 
            "added_commits": [
                {
                    "File_Names": [
                        "115\t0\t1/src/hello.cpp",
                        "116\t0\t1/src/hell1o.cpp"
                    ], 
                }
            ], 
            "project_name": "android/hello"
        }, 
       {
            "prev_revision": "a09936ea19ddc9f69ed00a7929ea81234af82b95", 
            "added_commits": [
                {
                    "File_Names": [
                        "41\t1\t1/src/hello1.cpp" 
                    ], 
                }
            ], 
            "project_name": "android/helloworld"
        }

    ]
}
```

> output.txt

```
115 0   1/src/hello.cpp
116 0   1/src/hell1o.cpp
41  1   1/src/hello1.cpp
```

> expected output.txt

```
android/hello/src/hello.cpp
android/hello/src/hell1o.cpp
android/helloworld/src/hello1.cpp
```

Comment: As an aside: looking at your expected output, you also want to get rid of the leading "1" in the file path as well, which exists in the third column. I'd just split on "/" (forward slash) and get rid of the first value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick

```
import json
import re
with open('data.json') as f:
    x = json.load(f)

for sub_dict in x['changed']:
    proj = sub_dict['project_name']

    for entry in sub_dict['added_commits']:
        for name in entry['File_Names']:
            n = re.findall(r'(?:\s*\d+\s*\d+\s*\d+)(\/.*)', name)[0]
            print( proj + n)
```

Note the use of `with` to open the file which will also close it afterwards.

I used regex to make this more robust, this will get anything of the from  `numbers   numbers  numbers/stuff_to_match`

Comment: Thank you very much for your support.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate through the sub-lists like this:

```
for d in x['changed']:
    for c in d['added_commits']:
        for f in c['File_Names']:
            print(d['project_name'] + f.split('\t')[2][1:])
```

This outputs:

```
android/hello/src/hello.cpp
android/hello/src/hell1o.cpp
android/helloworld/src/hello1.cpp
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support.